# Adding two lists representing numbers in prolog

Tags: prolog

The task says: the numbers are represented by lists (e.g. 123 = [1, 2, 3]), write a predicate which adds two such numbers. (e.g. `sum([4, 5, 6], [9], [4, 6, 5])`).

I have been thinking how to express this recursively but what trips me up is when the sizes of the arrays vary. It seems, that this would be simple if the arrays were reverted, so that HEAD is actually the last element. Because the problem for me is that my sum looks like that that:

```
  [4, 5, 6]
+
  [9]
```

instead of

```
  [4, 5, 6]
+
        [9]
```

What could be the proper way to write such predicate? I need some pointers or reference for help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my implementation:

```
sum(L1,L2,OutL):-
         reverse(L1,List1),reverse(L2,List2),
         add_lists(List1,List2,0,List3),
         reverse(List3,OutL).

add_lists([],[],0,[]).
add_lists([],[],1,[1]).
add_lists([],[H|T],C,[H1|T]):-H1 is H+C.
add_lists([H|T],[],C,[H1|T]):-H1 is H+C.
add_lists([H|T],[H1|T1],C,[H2|T2]):-NH is H1+H,
                         (NH > 10 -> NC is 1,H2 is NH+C-10; H2 is NH+C,NC is 0),
                          add_lists(T,T1,NC,T2).
```

The idea is to reverse lists in order to add right positions and avoid the problem you referred. Also you just keep a carry which is 1 if an addition is greater than 10 where you reduce 10.

Example:

```
?- sum([4, 5, 6], [9], L).
L = [4, 6, 5] ;
false.
```